# For what values of $k$ is $\lim_{x \to \infty} e^{-3x} \cosh kx$ finite?

Tags: limits

For what values of $k$ is $\lim_{x \to \infty} e^{-3x} \cosh kx$ finite?

Any help would be appreciated. The way this question is worded is really stumping me on where to go here.

Comment: Hint: Use the exponential form of $\cosh.$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:** Rewrite all as exponentials, using the alternate form of $\cosh$.
From $$\cosh t = \frac{e^t+e^{-t}}{2}$$
you get
$$
e^{-3x}\cosh kx = e^{-3x} \frac{e^{kx}+e^{-kx}}{2}
= \frac{e^{(k-3)x}+e^{-(k+3)x}}{2}
$$
Now, for which value(s) of $k$ does the RHS not blow up to $\infty$ when $x\to+\infty$?